# Как Получить текст из строки поиска?

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, macos

Не могу ни одним известным мне способом получения данных из вебэлемента сделать это. Прошу о помощи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело вот в чем. Мой код переходит в раздел images в Yandex.ru
и кликает по первой категории картинок. Далее мне нужно убедиться в том, что в строке поиска указан верный текст

```
def MakeSomeClick():
    driver.get('https://yandex.ru/images/')
    pos1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('PopularRequestList-Item_pos_0')
    name1 = pos1.get_attribute('data-grid-text')
    pos1.click()
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, пример вашего кода, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться :)

Comment: откуда берется "верный текст"?

Comment: При нажатии на категорию Картинок, название этой категории дублируется в строку поиска